# How to fix the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first attempt on doing webs craping. I am trying to scrap reviews from a website using this code as the reference:

```
#import webdriver from local path
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
#targeted url address
url = "https://website.com/"
#get response from url
response = browser.get(url)

category_root = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jsx-3285079627.category-landing-list')
category_column = category_root.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'jsx-3285079627.category-landing-column')

#list of category
list_of_category = []
list_of_href = []

for i in category_column:
    get_category_name = i.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
    for cat in get_category_name:
        list_of_category.append(cat.text)
        list_of_href.append(cat.get_attribute('href'))
        
print(list_of_category)
print(list_of_href)
```

This error is thrown:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 category_root = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jsx-3285079627.category-landing-list')
----> 2 category_column = category_root.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'jsx-3285079627.category-landing-column')
      4 #list of category
      5 list_of_category = []

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'
```

Answer (score 1):

`browser.find_elements` returns an array of `WebElement`s, not a single `WebElement`. So, basically, `category_root` is now an array, not a single object. You can check the array if any element is present, and if so, use `category_root[0].find_elements(...)` to find subelements. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement for the API docs.